# how to get actual content of an object after being replaceWith('something') in jquery

Tags: jquery, this, replacewith

I have this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.selector').click(function(){
        obj = $(this);
        obj.replaceWith('<div class="size">whats up man ??!</div>');
        alert(obj.html());
    });
});
```

I want to get the new content of 'obj' that has been 'replaceWith'

but,

I get the old content instead ...

how do I get the actual content of 'obj' ???

my intention is to access the new 'obj'

```
$('.selector').click(function(){
            var obj = $(this),
            repl = $('<div class="size">whats up man ??! <span class="medium"></span></div>');
            obj.replaceWith(repl);
            alert(obj.find('span').attr('class')); //this will print 'undefined'
});
```

I want to print the class name of the 'span' which is 'medium'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your updated method is the correct one, just needs a tweak like this:

```
$('.selector').click(function(){
  var obj = $(this),
      repl = $('<div class="size">whats up man ??! <span class="medium"></span></div>');
  obj.replaceWith(repl);
  alert(repl.find('span').attr('class')); 
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/HCXaK/).  The important change is the `repl.find()` to look in the new element instead of the old one.

Answer (score 3):

why do you want to do that? you know what you replaced it with....

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.selector').click(function(){
        var obj = $(this);
        var replacement = $('<div class="size">whats up man ??!</div>');
        obj.replaceWith(replacement);
        alert(replacement.html());
    });
});
```

Comment: thx andrew,

my intention is to have access to manipulate everything inside the actual 'obj',

$('.size').click(function(){
 var obj = $(this),
 repl = $('<div class="size">whats up man ??! <span class="medium"></span></div>');
        obj.replaceWith(repl);
 alert(obj.find('span').attr('class')); // this will print 'undefined'
        // I want to get the class name from the actual 'obj'
});

Comment: but you know you just assigned `size` to it, so why aren't just just alerting `size`? just do: `replacement.find('span').attr('class')` if you really must

Comment: yes andrew, your code has solved my question in the first place. but I think I missunderstood. here is the final result http://jsfiddle.net/HCXaK/1/