# Jquery: how to execute a function after all functions in replacement are executed for replaceWith() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replacewith

For Jquery replaceWith(newCode) method:

The new code contains a number of scripts to executed when document is ready. For example

```
<div>
    <script>$(function(){ foo1(); });</script>
    <script>$(function(){ foo2(); });</script>
    <script>$(function(){ foo3(); });</script>
</div>
```

After replaceWith(...) is called,
function foo4(..) needs to execute after foo1(), foo2(), and foo3() are executed.

I tried this:

```
 $(".foo").replaceWith(newCode);
 $(function(){ foo4(); }
```

But foo4() is called before foo1, foo2, and foo3.

How to execute a function after all functions (document ready) in the replacement code are executed?

Comment: Insert it into `newCode`. or... better yet, avoid doing this all together.

Comment: NO. This is just a simplified case. Just a case for searching solution.

Comment: You can "fix" it with a setTimeout, but you won't find any non-hacky solution to your hacky problem.

Comment: Timeout is not reliable. Have to hate it.

Comment: It may not be reliable, but there's no event you can wait on that makes sense for your scenario. You don't have any other real options.

Comment: It seems the functions in the new code are not registered with document ready when the replaceWith() is executed.

Comment: The reason it works this way is because foo 1 2 and 3 can't run until the code that is inserting 1 2 and 3 completes, which will be *after* foo4's ready handler has been bound. So you must push the call off to the call stack in a way that guarentees it will be ran *after* 1 2 and 3 have ran. setTimeout is the only real option.

Comment: well, aside from not doing this (aka not using replaceWith or anything similar) at all and taking an entirely different approach. such as *not* appending html to your page that contains scripts.

Comment: Jquery should run the scripts inside the new code in the replaceWith(...) method. This way it would register foo1/2/3 with document ready before foo4 is registered. Do not know why jQuery does not do it this way.

Comment: that's not how the dom works. jquery has nothing to do with why this isn't working.

Comment: But replaceWith is a Jquery method, right?

Comment: Yes, it is, but all that does is use the DOM api to insert the html you've provided into the location of the old element. It isn't going to strip the code out for you and run it at a convenient time.

Comment: I see. Why DOM does not run the scripts inside the new code immediately after replacement is finished? When the scripts will be run?

Comment: Javascript is single threaded. It can't run new code until existing code has finished running.

Comment: setTimeout would likely be more reliable than you might think in this scenario, even if it is a bit hacky.

Comment: Single-threading helps me understand it. Thanks.

Comment: Even javascript is single threading, DOM API can get the scripts out from the new code and run them in the same thread. It is technically possible. right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery wait for replaceWith to finish before executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24429210/jquery-wait-for-replacewith-to-finish-before-executing)