# Getting undefined even though it is defined ( JavaScript )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

Trying to write a basic jQuery plugin:

### HTML:

```
<textarea>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
</textarea>
```

### jQuery:

```
$.fn.wysiwyg = function (options) {

    var e = $(this).replaceWith("<iframe>");
    console.log($(this)[0].contentDocument);

};
$("textarea").wysiwyg();
```

### [JSFIDDLE DEMONSTRATION](http://jsfiddle.net/iamfaizahmed/u0qwkcb9/3/)

### The Problem

```
var e = $(this).replaceWith("<iframe>");
console.log($(this)[0].contentDocument);
```

I am getting `undefined` at the console. If I set an id attribute to this iframe and target that `id` in `console.log` method, it works perfectly, but I want to use `$(this)`. What can be done for this?

Comment: simply use this not jquery $(this)

Comment: because `this` still refers to the textarea

Comment: @C-linkNepal `console.log(this[0].contentDocument);` or `console.log(this.contentDocument);` doesn't works.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks but I know why this is happening. I am asking for the solution.

Comment: Maybe you could try and use 'iframe' in console.log? Here's an example that `finds` `span` with `class` in jquery function.     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573521/how-to-get-actual-content-of-an-object-after-being-replacewithsomething-in-j

Comment: [jQuery replaceWith find new element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118778/jquery-replacewith-find-new-element)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `this` will still refer to the `textarea` so

```
$.fn.wysiwyg = function (options) {

    var $frame = $("<iframe>")
    var e = $(this).replaceWith($frame);
    console.log($frame[0].contentDocument);

};
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7odzx2x5/)

Comment: Maybe this iframe will collide with other iframes in the document, whatever I do with my plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$.fn.wysiwyg = function (options) {

    var $e = $("<iframe>");
    this.replaceWith($e);
    console.log($e);

};


$("textarea").wysiwyg();
```

:: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u0qwkcb9/4/) ::